# How to include .java files from another directory in my intelliJ module?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have the following project:

[image]

And now I want to use the Files which are marked green  in my MainActivity (for example) in another module. In my case 'Vertretungsplan'

Do I have to include this directory in my build.gradle and how?
I use Android Studio. So its the same like IntelliJ